# What is known about the QuartzFilter class?

Tags: cocoa

[This mailing-list thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/210714-pdfkit-guidance.html) states that there is a QuartzFilter class in the Mac OS X SDKs that can be used manipulate, well, Quartz filters. But… this class is undocumented as far as I can tell, and I couldn't find any more information on it with Google.

A quick use of `nm` reveals that the `QuartzFilter.framework` has the following public methods:

```
000000000001577a t +[QuartzFilter converterProperties:allObjects:images:imageBPC:imageRenderingIntent:]
0000000000015364 t +[QuartzFilter hostMatchingFilter:imageBPC:imageRenderingIntent:]
00000000000152a5 t +[QuartzFilter imageConverter:bpc:renderingIntent:]
0000000000015465 t +[QuartzFilter quartzFilterWithOutputIntents:]
00000000000155df t +[QuartzFilter quartzFilterWithProperties:]
0000000000015522 t +[QuartzFilter quartzFilterWithURL:]
```

but, all these create filter objects, how do you apply them to something?

Comment: A lowercase `t` means that thses symbols are **not** exported, thus they can’t be public.

Comment: The header files ***are*** available and public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, these classes are very poorly documented. In fact, there seems to be virtually no documentation at all, even in the headers.

You don't need to use `nm` to see the API. Use **File > Open Quickly** in Xcode and type `QuartzFilter` into the dialog. You'll be able to open `QuartzFilter.h` and `QuartzFilterManager.h`.

Looks like you could use this to get an array of all available filters:

```
[[QuartzFilterManager filterManager] filtersInDomains:nil];
```

Once you have a filter, you can apply it to a `CGContext` with `-applyToContext:`.

You can create filters in the ColorSync utility, but how you go about creating one programmatically is a mystery. I guess if you instantiate one of the existing filters using its URL then you could use the various methods of `QuartzFilter` to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

QuartzFilters are [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/quartzfilter?language=objc), but very poorly. As said, you can apply them to a CGContext or as a dictionary when writing a PDF using PDFKit (PDFDocument).